# Code Igniter Search returns all records in table when input value is empty

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, post

Search results shows all the records when the keywords input is empty, how can I display a message that says search term not found?

What if I want to add another input value too, like input->post('date') ?

Controller:

```
$keywords = $this->input->post('keywords');

$data['results'] = $this->search_model->get_results($keywords );
$this->template->show('results',$data);
```

Model:

```
function get_results($keywords = 'default'){

       $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('list')
       ->where("name LIKE '%$keywords%'")->get();

       return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using codeigniter `$this->db->like` method.
If your `$keyward` is empty then try this...

```
$keywords = $this->input->post('keywords');
if(!empty($keywords)){
   $data['results'] = $this->search_model->get_results($keywords ); 
}else{
$data['result']="not found";
}
$this->template->show('results',$data);
```

**Or**

```
function get_results($keywords = null){

   if(!$keywords){
   return false;
   }
   $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('list')->like("name",$keywords)->get();
   return $query->result_array();
}
```

Every time your query run and return data because you pass $keyword='default' so if `$keyword` is empty then it search using **default** 
[For more.....](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have a like statement.

So if you write,

`select * from list where name like '%%';`

It will return all.

if you have a empty keyword better you not go for database, since you don't have anything to search.